# Autowire class with generic type parameter

Tags: java, spring, autowired

If I have a interface  that has a type parameter , and an implementation of that interface like so:

```java
public interface BaseService<T> {
    List<T> getAll();
    Optional<T> findById(long id);
    T save(T user);
    void delete(long id);
}

@Service
public class UserService implements BaseService<User> {
```

Is it possible at all to do something like this?

```java
class BaseThingController<T> {
    @Autowired
    private BaseService<T> service;
```

ATM it tells me a bean cannot be found with that, just wondering if theres a way to make this work

Comment: hm, Im tryna achieve full abstraction here, whats the closest i could probably get to this?

Comment: BaseThingController isnt actually annotated with @Controller, its subclasses are tho, for example a subclass of BaseThingController would be like class Thing extends BaseThingController<User>

Comment: I need to be able to access the service in the parent